# "Unable to locate element" error without sleep instruction

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phpunit

I have the following Selenium test :

```
class MyTest extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase
{
    public function testFunction() {
        $this->url('https://mywebsiteurl.com');

        // ...
        // Several selenium actions here
        // ...

        $this->byId('form-submit-button')->click(); // Submit a form to another URL
        $this->byId('next')->click();
    }
}
```

And randomly, my test fails with the following error :

```
PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_WebDriverException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"next"}
Command duration or timeout: 49 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.40.0', revision: 'fbe29a9', time: '2014-02-19 20:54:28'
System info: host: 'selenium-server', ip: '15.121.50.61', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.2.0-4-amd64', java.version: '1.6.0_27'
Session ID: 4e7822e4-73dc-473e-8010-6717a04d243e
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{platform=LINUX, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, version=24.6.0, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, handlesAlerts=true, browserConnectionEnabled=true, nativeEvents=false, webStorageEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true}]
```

When I see the generated screenshot, I can see the button is "next" present on my Web page and when I add a "sleep(5)" instruction before calling the "click" method, my test passes everytime.

Do you know how to solve my problem ?

Ben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a java guy.. But, as per your question I would recommend you to go for either [implicit or explicit waits](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits) to solve your problem..

On googling, I found this code for implicit wait that you can use here to solve your problem:

```
$this->timeouts()->implicitWait(30000);
```

Add this at the top of the code above `$this->url('https://mywebsiteurl.com');`. This will ensure that, **each time selenium tries to locate an element it will wait a maximum of 30 seconds.** Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh! My bad.. It should be maximum.. have edited it.. Thanks @Vivek for pointing that out.. :)